# Mouse cursor jumps

Tags: linux, linux-mint, mouse, cursor

I have a laptop with a Windows 10 and Linux Mint MATE dual boot.

I noticed that when I'm using the laptop mousepad, the cursor jumps to the border of the screen. If I swipe my finger slowly, the cursor slides normally, but if I swipe my finger just a little bit faster, the cursor jumps to the border of the screen. It does not jump with an external USB mouse.

Comment: Possibly a mouse acceleration setting configured for your touch pad?

Comment: I really don't know. How can I check this ?

Comment: It depends on what window manager you are using. Since you tagged Linux Mint, I’m guessing this would be somewhere within your settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

The freedesktop project provides hints for debugging on
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-jumping-cursors.html

It suggests to run

```
# libinput record
```

as root and monitor the output to find a scheme behind the jumps.